# Need help to update python in ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

when I check my python version using the following commands:
#python --version
Python 3.7.13

#python3 --version
Python 3.7.13

I get a different version of python

And when I used this command
/root/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/python --version
Python 3.7.4
I get this version of python

I want to update this python version: 3.7.4 which is there in /root/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/python
I want to update python 3.7.4 to 3.10

Comment: Let me know if the below answer works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a Conda environment, specifically an environment named "tensorflow". If you wish to update the Python version for this Conda environment to 3.10

First, activate the Conda environment that you wish to update:

```
source /root/miniconda3/bin/activate tensorflow
```

Now, try updating Python to 3.10 within the active Conda environment:

```
conda install python=3.10
```

This command will attempt to update Python to version 3.10 within the "tensorflow" environment.

However, be aware that doing this might cause incompatibilities with some of the existing packages installed in the environment.

Conda will typically try to resolve these and might update, downgrade, or remove some packages to accommodate the new Python version.

Once updated, you can verify the Python version in the current environment

```
python --version
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Before updating the Python, do you recommend backing up or copying some files?
Which files should I back and will it be possible for me to go back to version 3.7.4 if something goes wrong?

Comment: When upgrading Python or any software, it's generally a good idea to have some form of backup, especially if you have critical or customized settings or packages.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create an env `conda create --name myenv python=3.10`  with that specific python version, so that it will not conflict with the other projects that use python=3.7.4. https://saturncloud.io/blog/updating-python-to-a-specific-version-using-conda-a-guide/